# VBA to transpose data based on empty lines

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Data-raw]

I have an EXTREMELY large data set in excel with varying data sets (some have 12 lines and some with 18, etc) that are currently in rows that needs to be transposed to columns. All the groupings are separated by a empty/blank line. 
I started the VBA to transpose this it but dont know how to include/look at the blank line and loop it to the end of each sheet. Any ideas/suggestions?

[image: output]

```
    Range("F1:F12").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
Sheets("Sheet3").Select
Range("F14:F27").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Range("A2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
Range("G14").Select
```

Comment: My first idea is that you give us more information. What does your data look like, what should it look like? Post a screenshot.

Comment: Sorry I updated the above with images.

Comment: I'm still unclear about what you are doing. You seem to be transposing but changing the order of some cells. Where are the blank lines?

Comment: updated the raw data file. each "data group" has varying set of lines, and the blank lines separate each "group" of data. the range changes with each data set, it could be 12 lines or 13, etc but each set is separated by a blank line.

Comment: I see now. Do you want all the blocks of cell transposed to row 1 of the other sheet, or move down a row each time?

Comment: You might want to try using a pivot table.

Comment: ideally, transposed to another sheet, starting at row 1.

Comment: all the data is separated by a line so pivoting will not work. i would have to do it over 13K

Comment: If you have different numbers of rows for each section, and you transpose, won't you have a problem getting the columns of similar data to coincide?  If so, how do you want to handle that?

Comment: Ron, that would be relatively easy clean up via excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using `Select` statements at all costs and when possible, use the `Array` data structure to process data. Processing data in `Arrays` is much faster than reading/writing from the worksheet. The Procedure below should do what you want. Note that although it's not ideal to use `ReDim Preserve` in a loop, however, I have used it for row counts of over 100,000 with no issue. Point being, 13,000 rows should be no problem.

```
Sub Transpose()
 Dim Data_Array
 Dim OutPut_Array()
 Dim LR As Long, Counter As Long, LR2 As Long
 Dim i As Long

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  'Find the last row of your data in Sheet3 Column A 
  'I added 1 so that the conditional statement below 
  'doesn't exclude the last row of data
  With Sheets("Sheet3")
     LR = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
     Data_Array = .Range("A1:A" & LR).Value2
  End With 

    'See explanation in the edit section below 
    On Error Resume Next 
    For i = LBound(Data_Array, 1) To UBound(Data_Array, 1)

        'if the cell is not blank then increase the counter by one
        'and for each non blank cell in the Data_Array, 
        'add it to the OutPut_Array
        'If its not blank then output the prepopulated OutPut_Array to Sheet4 and 
        'set the counter back to zero 
        If Trim(Data_Array(i, 1)) <> vbNullString Then
            Counter = Counter + 1

            ReDim Preserve OutPut_Array(1 To 1, 1 To Counter)

            OutPut_Array(1, Counter) = Data_Array(i, 1)

        Else

            With Sheets("Sheet4")
                LR2 = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                .Range("A" & LR2 + 1).Resize(1, Counter).Value2 = OutPut_Array
            End With

            Counter = 0
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

**Test Data:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

This could also be done with a `nested dictionary` however in this case it would need to be assisted by array to create a one to many relationship using conditional statements, and then transposing the dictionary, but I am still trying to perfect that method so I went with the above, lol. Hope this is helpful.

**Edit:** Added `On Error Resume Next` as per OP's request for the procedure to work even if there is more than one blank between the rows of data. In this case `On Error Resume Next` avoids the `Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or Object Defined Error` associated with the Range.Resize property. The error is thrown when the if statement is looking at occurences of a blank cells greater than 1. In the else portion of the statement, the counter variable would be equal to 0, thus causing the second dimension of the range to be 0 and throwing the error. If the cells in column A are truly blank as the OP suggests, then this is a valid method to trap the error. Also added the `Trim()` function to handle blank cells that may have spaces.

Comment: OMG This definitely works, only issue that i have now, is that it only reads about 17K lines/row at ones and i have over 350K lines/rpw to read but at least this works!!! Is there a way that this vba can be modified to read more row at one?

Comment: @Hopelessdreamz Awesome! Except for the only reading 17,000 Lines part, lol. I am betting that there is some sort of break in the data larger than one space at the 17K mark. What does the data look like at row 17000ish?

Comment: You truly are a master. There were an extra line break in there so it stopped. Thanks again. Would it be able to read more or work more?

Comment: @Hopelessdreamz Let me put my thinking cap on again and I shall be back!

Comment: @Hopelessdreamz I found the quick fix. Add `On Error Resume Next` directly above `For i = LBound(Data_Array, 1) To UBound(Data_Array, 1)`. This works even if there are >=n blank cells between the data. **Disclaimer:** You just have to be for absolute sure that the blank Cells in Column A between your data are truly blank Cells.

Comment: @Hopelessdreamz You are most welcome! I love doing this stuff so I am happy to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Try adapting this.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range
application.screenupdating=false
For Each r In Sheet1.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Areas
    r.Copy
    Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    'Sheet2.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
Next r
application.screenupdating=true    
End Sub
```