# Using VBA & VLOOKUP to reorganize column ranges into rows

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have two columns for year 2019, one has months and the other amounts corresponding to that month. I would like to re-organize it with months as headers and the amounts underneath, as can be seen on the attached screenshot.

[image]

I used VLOOKUP for the first couple but there's over 100,000 rows and it would take forever to manually update the range for each VLOOKUP.

The problem is that not all the data is uniform. It would be great if the data started in January and ended in December, but that's not the case. Take a look at the second screenshot

[image]

which shows data beginning in July and ending in December and some begin in January and end in July. Towards the end of the data set, there are hundreds of new accounts that opened in December, so the only available data is just for the month of December. So, it varies.

Is there a way to utilize VBA and VLOOKUP to automatically sort the columns with one header, i.e. months 1-12, and all the amounts underneath? This data will then be merged with the user account information, that's why I would like to have it all in 1 row.

If you have other suggestions please let me know. Any help is appreciated!

P.S. I found this link to be useful for transposing ranges separated by blank rows: [VBA to transpose data based on empty lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54426859/vba-to-transpose-data-based-on-empty-lines?rq=1)

How can I incorporate VLOOKUP in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an option. It uses the month to determine which column (from D onwards) to place the value. It moves to a new row once it finds one or more blank rows between the datasets.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Process()

    Dim TargetRow As Long
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim DateCell As Range
    Dim LastRowWasBlank As Boolean

    Set SourceRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & ActiveSheet.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    TargetRow = 2
    For Each DateCell In SourceRange
        If DateCell.Cells(1, 1) <> "" Then
            LastRowWasBlank = False
            ActiveSheet.Cells(TargetRow, 3 + Month(DateCell.Cells(1, 1))) = DateCell.Cells(1, 2)
        Else
            If LastRowWasBlank <> True Then
                LastRowWasBlank = True
                TargetRow = TargetRow + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

[image: capture]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you already found the solution for getting the data using VLookup. You didn't find the solution how to copy the formulas to 100K cells. Here it is.

1. Select the cell with the original formula
2. Copy (you can use Ctl+C)
3. On the Home Tab click *Find & Select* and then *Goto ...*
4. In the *Reference* field write the target range, like *B2:K500000*
5. Click *OK* (This will select the target range)
6. Press *Enter* (This will complete the pasting operation)

Comment: Thank you for the response. That does not work because the range that is used in the vlookup is dynamic. For example, A1:B13 is the range used for the first row. Range A17:B28, is the second range which makes up the second row, and so on.

Comment: There must be an identifier in C:C for each row of the result and that must be taken from somewhere, not included in your post. Please modify the pictures of your data to include that identifier.

Comment: There is not. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

### Transpose With Empty Cells

- Copy the complete code into a standard module (e.g. `Module1`).
- Carefully adjust the values in the constants section.
- Run only the `Sub`. The `Function` is called by the `Sub`.

**The Code**

```
Sub transposeMonths()

    ' Define constants.
    Const srcNameOrIndex As Variant = "Sheet1"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const SourceColumn As Long = 1
    Const ValueColumn As Long = 2
    Const tgtNameOrIndex As Variant = "Sheet1"
    Const tgtFirstCell As String = "D1"
    Const Separator As String = "-"
    Dim CurrYear As Long: CurrYear = 2019
    Dim Months As Variant
    Months = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", _
                   "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    ' Add Separator and Current Year to Months Array.
    Dim ubM As Long: ubM = UBound(Months)
    Dim j As Long
    For j = 0 To ubM
        Months(j) = Months(j) & Separator & CurrYear
    Next j
    Months = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Months))
    ubM = ubM + 1

    ' Read from Source Ranges to Source Arrays.
    Dim src As Worksheet: Set src = wb.Worksheets(srcNameOrIndex)
    Dim Source(1) As Variant
    Source(0) = getColumnValues(src, SourceColumn, FirstRow)
    Dim ubS As Long: ubS = UBound(Source(0))
    Source(1) = src.Cells(FirstRow, ValueColumn).Resize(ubS)
    Set src = Nothing

    ' Count unique items.
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim CurrMonth As String, i As Long
    For i = 1 To ubS
        CurrMonth = Source(0)(i, 1)
        If CurrMonth <> "" Then
            dict(CurrMonth) = dict(CurrMonth) + 1
        End If
    Next i

    ' Write from Source Arrays to Target Array.
    Dim Target As Variant
    ReDim Target(1 To Application.Max(dict.Items) + 1, 1 To ubM)
    For j = 1 To ubM
        Target(1, j) = Months(j)
    Next j
    For i = ubS To 1 Step -1
        CurrMonth = Source(0)(i, 1)
        If CurrMonth <> "" Then
            Target(dict(CurrMonth) + 1, Application.Match(CurrMonth, Months, 0)) _
              = Source(1)(i, 1)
            dict(CurrMonth) = dict(CurrMonth) - 1
        End If
    Next i

    ' Write from Target Array to Target Range.
    Dim tgt As Worksheet: Set tgt = wb.Worksheets(tgtNameOrIndex)
    tgt.Range(tgtFirstCell).Resize(UBound(Target), UBound(Target, 2)) = Target

    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Data copied.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Writes the values of a non-empty one-column range starting     '
'               from a specified row, to a 2D one-based one-column array.      '
' Returns:      A 2D one-based one-column array.                               '
' Remarks:      If the column is empty or its last non-empty row is above      '
'               the specified row or if an error occurs the function will      '
'               return an empty variant. Therefore the function's result       '
'               can be tested with "IsEmpty".                                  '
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function getColumnValues(Sheet As Worksheet, _
                         Optional ByVal AnyColumn As Variant = 1, _
                         Optional ByVal FirstRow As Long = 1) _
        As Variant

    On Error GoTo exitProcedure
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet.Columns(AnyColumn).Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If rng.Row < FirstRow Then Exit Function
    Set rng = Sheet.Range(Sheet.Cells(FirstRow, AnyColumn), rng)

    Dim Result As Variant
    If rng.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        ReDim Result(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Result(1, 1) = rng.Value
    Else
        Result = rng.Value
    End If
    getColumnValues = Result

exitProcedure:
End Function
```